# Onclick event on dynamically inserted elements doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, jquery-events

When I insert the following code by JavaScript into my HTML then the `onclick` event doesn't work (`load_menu` doesn't run). But when I insert this code manually it works.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" onclick="load_menu('dropdown-menu',10001)" data-toggle="dropdown">رباتیک<i class="icon-arrow open"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu show" id="10001">
    </ul>
</li>
```

Javascript code:

```
function load_menu(m,id) {
    var t = 1000;
    if (m == 'dropdown') {
        if ($('div.container ul li[class="dropdown"]').length == 0) {
            loadXMLDoc("GET", "ContainerMenu.aspx?m=" + m + "&id=" + id, function (result) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
                
                toggle_menu();
            });
            
        }
    }
    if (m == 'dropdown-menu') {
        if ($('div.container ul li ul[class="dropdown-menu"]').length == 0) {
            loadXMLDoc("GET", "ContainerMenu.aspx?m=" + m + "&id=" + id, function (result) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
                
                toggle_menu();
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your JS? We need to see that to before we can attempt to help you....

Comment: The JavaScript code you used is more important. Please edit that in.

Comment: make sure you have a js function which takes 2 variables called load_menu. If its external, make sure you import it properly, you can test by moving the function locally first.

Comment: Well, what you included doesn't have an error.

Comment: So... You're showing us the working version and asking us why the non-working version (which you aren't showing us) doesn't work?

Comment: i hope i wont see jquery´s append appending this

Comment: Not sure why they are relying on js for this. This should be done server side(preferably) or hard coded -.-

Comment: Show us the JS, that's what we are going to debug on! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML='<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" onclick="load_menu('dropdown-menu',10001)" data-toggle="dropdown">رباتیک<i class="icon-arrow open"></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu show" id="10001"></ul></li>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/955uM/
you will notice the  'dropdown-menu' is not highlighted and not included into the string. use this instead:

```
document.body.innerHTML='<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" onclick="load_menu('+"'dropdown-menu'"+',10001)" data-toggle="dropdown">رباتیک<i class="icon-arrow open"></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu show" id="10001"></ul></li>'
```

Comment: first show dropdown then by click on <a> show dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when the onclick on html elements created in code would not trigger. In the below sample code the button created in code shows up but nothing happens when it is clicked

```
<html> 
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 
   alert("page is loading");
   function createbuttonincode() {
      var div=document.getElementById("testdiv");
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      var buttononclickstring = "javacript:testbuttonclick()";
      button.setAttribute ("onclick",  buttononclickstring);
      button.innerHTML = "button created by code";
      div.appendChild(button);
   }
   function testbuttonclick()
   {
       alert("button click event fired");
   }
</script> 
</head>
<body> 
<form> 
   <input type=button onclick="javascript:createbuttonincode()"  value="Create new button"/> 
<div id="testdiv"></div>
</form> 
</body>
```

But if I add this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

in the head then the click event on the dynamically created event fires and I see the alert.

Seems like this is not an issue for Edge browser